# java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: Package signed with debug key (go/gsrlt)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play-console

My app in google play console is crashed with this error below

```
java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: Package signed with debug key (go/gsrlt)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1958)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1904)
at lqp.x(PG:12)
at lor$c.a(PG:7)
at lor$f.run(PG:4)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
at ltp.run(Unknown Source:6)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

can anyone tell me what is the problem ? and how to fix this ??????????

Comment: Same here. But only in the Pre-launch report. I guess it is an issue with the Google test devices, because I can see in the video it happens while a file share intent when Google Drive was selected.

Comment: According to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64196715, it's a bug in an old version of google play services which is installed on some devices.

Answer (score 4):

I also get this exception on Google Play Console. I think it's a bug in the Samsung Galaxy S9 test device which Google uses. When I watched the testing video it occurs when the bot tries to share the app via Google Drive.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: Package signed with debug key (go/gsrlt)

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.google.android.apps.docs, PID: 16940
    java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: Package signed with debug key (go/gsrlt)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1958)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1904)
        at mer.x(PG:12)
        at mcs$c.a(PG:7)
        at mcs$f.run(PG:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at mhr.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```