# Google Maps Unable to update local snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier

Tags: android, google-maps

I have the following error on my Google Maps app

```
Unable to update local snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier#com.example.my_app, may result in stale flags.     
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.example.my_app, sha256=[098355cb7da096c1c7d98fa16db67e136db0a35aa540229aec9f8801f6355789], atk=false, ver=223017031.true (go/gsrlt)
                at ahy.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223017068@22.30.17 (100700-0):3)
                at ahy.get(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223017068@22.30.17 (100700-0):2)
                at aji.g(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223017068@22.30.17 (100700-0):2)
                at xy.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223017068@22.30.17 (100700-0):1)
                at ya.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223017068@22.30.17 (100700-0):0)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
```

It was working fine yesterday,but now when starting the app on the emulator the map is blank,the rest of the components like buttons are intact.
I did not change anything in my code all my dependencies and my API key is correct.

What could be the problem?

Comment: I've been having the same problem since just now. How did you solve these?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I fixed with this post:

[SecurityException - GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64196715/securityexception-googlecertificatesrslt-not-allowed)

I hope you find it useful :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Downvoted because it does not indicate which answer was the solution.

Comment: Completely agree. He should have used the Share link to the answer, not the link to the question. I guess I have to try all of these now.