# java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, android-jetpack-compose

I am working on MVVM app and I am getting the following error when using location tracking with [GoogleMap](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/maps-compose) composable:

```kt
2022-10-02 18:43:48.734 31711-31750/com.park.reserved W/MobStoreFlagStore: Unable to update local snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier#com.park.reserved, may result in stale flags.
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.park.reserved, sha256=[462925ab37c5ec4ab8550323438372023f34e9897a556848dd8c35d18c4e71c6], atk=false, ver=223616044.true (go/gsrlt)
        at ahn.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223616044@22.36.16 (190400-0):3)
        at ahn.get(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223616044@22.36.16 (190400-0):2)
        at aix.g(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223616044@22.36.16 (190400-0):2)
        at xq.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223616044@22.36.16 (190400-0):1)
        at xs.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223616044@22.36.16 (190400-0):0)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:463)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.park.reserved, sha256=[462925ab37c5ec4ab8550323438372023f34e9897a556848dd8c35d18c4e71c6], atk=false, ver=223616044.true (go/gsrlt)
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2426)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2410)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2393)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2335)
        at em.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223616044@22.36.16 (190400-0):2)
        at rc.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223616044@22.36.16 (190400-0):4)
        at it.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223616044@22.36.16 (190400-0):2)
        at js.t(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223616044@22.36.16 (190400-0):2)
        at js.u(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223616044@22.36.16 (190400-0):3)
        at js.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223616044@22.36.16 (190400-0):2)
        at jw.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223616044@22.36.16 (190400-0):69)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

The app still runs when this happens, but the location tracking on GoogleMap compose doesn't work [I can successfully track the phone location, but I get the exception when trying to show the location on `GoogleMap` compose]

`Gradle:`

```kt
implementation "com.google.maps.android:maps-compose:2.7.2"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0"
```

I looked at the following similar StackOverflow post, but the error I'm getting is different: [SecurityException - GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64196715/securityexception-googlecertificatesrslt-not-allowed)

---

### The only way I was able to fix the issue is by creating the viewModel outside of the NavHost. The location tracking works doing it this way, but the exception still gets thrown in `Logcat`

Here's the code:

I have `SharedLocationManager` class that serves as location data source:

```kt
class SharedLocationManager constructor(
    private val context: Context,
    // The Fused Location Provider provides access to location APIs
    private val fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient =
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
) {
 
. . . 

}
```

I have `LocationRepository` class:

```kt
class LocationRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val sharedLocationManager: SharedLocationManager
) {
    // Observe flow for device last location updates
    fun lastLocation(): Flow<Location> = sharedLocationManager.lastLocationFlow()

    //  Observable flow for device location updates
    fun getLocationFlow(): SharedFlow<Location?> = sharedLocationManager.locationFlow()
}
```

I have `viewModel` that takes the `LocationRepository`:

```kt
@HiltViewModel
class FindParkingViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: LocationRepository // Data store from which to receive location updates via Flow, injected via Hilt
) : ViewModel() {

. . .
}
```

Then, I have a composable that takes the `viewModel` argument, gets the location from the viewModel and displays it on GoogleMaps:

```kt
@Composable
fun FindParking(findParkingViewModel: FindParkingViewModel) {
findParkingViewModel location has value
    val deviceCurrentLoc by findParkingViewModel.location.collectAsState(initial = null)

. . . 

    val cameraPosState = rememberCameraPositionState {
        position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(deviceCurrentLocLatLng, 12f)
    }



GoogleMap(
        modifier = modifier,
        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
        properties = mapProperties,
        uiSettings = uiSettings,
        onMapLoaded = onMapLoaded
    ) {
        
    }

}
```

Finally, I have the `NavHost`:

```kt
@Composable
fun MapAppNavHost(
    navController: NavHostController,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {

    // ** Creating the viewModel here solves the issue
    location tracking val findParkingViewModel: FindParkingViewModel = hiltViewModel()

    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = TopLevelDestination.Parking.route,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        composable(route = TopLevelDestination.Parking.route) {
            FindParking(findParkingViewModel)
        }

        . . .
      
    }
```

---

### Doing it the following way throws the exception:

I prefer `#1` approach because the code is cleaner.

`#1.` Assigning the viewModel as a default parameter throws an error:

```kt
@Composable
fun FindParking(findParkingViewModel: FindParkingViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    . . .
}
```

`#2` creating the `viewModel` within the `NavHost` `Composable` function also throws an error:

```kt
 NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = TopLevelDestination.Parking.route,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        composable(route = TopLevelDestination.Parking.route) {
            // ---> creating this here breaks it
            val findParkingViewModel: FindParkingViewModel = hiltViewModel()
            FindParking(findParkingViewModel)
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried almost every available solution and the only one which helped me, was: uninstalling the app from emulator and installing it again. It may sound stupid, but it worked for me.

Comment: check this comment in google issue tracker : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228091313#comment44