# BackupAccountManagerService: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

Got this error in unity app.
I've investigated a lot of similar problems
for example: [SecurityException - GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64196715/securityexception-googlecertificatesrslt-not-allowed),
but none of them contain the issue related to [Block Store](https://developers.google.com/identity/blockstore/android)
Why is this happening?

```
I/AppOps: updateUidProcState uid: 10227 procState: 3 capability:15
I/AppOps: commitUidPendingStateLocked() :: UID - 10227, 500 > 500, 8 > 15
D/NetworkPolicy: onUidStateChanged() uid: 10227, isForeground(true, 3)
? D/BoundBrokerSvc: onBind: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.auth.blockstore.service.START dat=chimera-action: cmp=com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsApiService }
? D/BoundBrokerSvc: Loading bound service for intent: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.auth.blockstore.service.START dat=chimera-action: cmp=com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsApiService }

[BackupAccountManagerService] Security Exception in getBackupAccount
    java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.example.app, sha256=[sha256 redacted], atk=false, ver=225014045.true (go/gsrlt)
        at yvp.d(:com.google.android.gms@225014045@22.50.14 (190408-499278674):3)
        at yvu.e(:com.google.android.gms@225014045@22.50.14 (190408-499278674):2)
        at udo.a(:com.google.android.gms@225014045@22.50.14 (190408-499278674):2)
        at uau.a(:com.google.android.gms@225014045@22.50.14 (190408-499278674):0)
        at uaw.b(:com.google.android.gms@225014045@22.50.14 (190408-499278674):4)
        at uaw.a(:com.google.android.gms@225014045@22.50.14 (190408-499278674):0)
        at nzy.b(:com.google.android.gms@225014045@22.50.14 (190408-499278674):1)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.blockstore.service.BlockstoreApiChimeraService.d(:com.google.android.gms@225014045@22.50.14 (190408-499278674):0)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.blockstore.service.BlockstoreApiChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms@225014045@22.50.14 (190408-499278674):4)
        at asoe.a(:com.google.android.gms@225014045@22.50.14 (190408-499278674):0)
        at aspc.a(:com.google.android.gms@225014045@22.50.14 (190408-499278674):0)
        at aspf.gi(:com.google.android.gms@225014045@22.50.14 (190408-499278674):45)
        at zwe.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@225014045@22.50.14 (190408-499278674):5)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1100)
        at alqf.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@225014045@22.50.14 (190408-499278674):17)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1100)
        at arlh.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@225014045@22.50.14 (190408-499278674):1)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1220)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1179)
```

I've tried changing android api level, installing the app from google app store, the local build, different devices, and android versions, in both cases the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created issue ticket on issue tracker service. And google fixed it. The fix will be available in the next version.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/266608214?pli=1