SecurityException: PackageVerificationRslt: not allowed when trying to use Google Maps in Android
For the past weeks, some of our users (but not all) have been experiencing this crash when opening Google Maps in the app:
java.lang.SecurityException: PackageVerificationRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.my.app, sha256=[<sha256 of our release signing key>], atk=false, ver=243700036.true
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3242)
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3226)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3209)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3151)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.getService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:46)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient.getRemoteService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:159)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaap.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:44)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaav.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:26)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:487)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:7)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

The chain of events that led to these crashes:

I added OAuth 2.0 Client ID corresponding to our debug key to Google Cloud Console to use Google Sign-In in debug builds (note: we use the same app ID for debug and release builds). Worked fine.

Subset of users in production started getting the above crash when trying to use Google Maps.

Asked the affected users to clear cache, data, restart the device, reinstall the app - nothing helped.

I removed the new Client ID.

Users still experience crashes.

After simply removing the new Client ID didn't resolve the issue, I also removed the old Client ID corresponding to the release build, and then immediately added it back. Didn't help.


I'm out of ideas how to approach these crashes and help the users. Will appreciate any help.

referred this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64196715/securityexception-googlecertificatesrslt-not-allowed

@sasikumar, yes, I read this thread. We already use Renderer.LATEST and I'm sure that our users use Google Play Services newer than 20.39.15. We haven't tried updating the Google Maps to the latest version yet, but we will, even though I can't see how this can be the reason for this crash to appear or persist.

We further updated the versions of Google's libs and released a new version. Crashes still happening.
